# noUiSlider value overwrite

Tags: jquery, nouislider

I'm trying to adapt noUiSlider to my needs. I would like to have a slider for 24 hours (1 day) but while I store values in 24-hr format, I want to show them on am/pm scale.

So this is a working function for 24 hours:

```
$('#time').noUiSlider({
    start: [ 5, 11 ],
    step: 1,
    connect: true,
    margin: 2,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 24
    },
    format: {
        to: function ( value ) {
            return value + ':00';
        },
        from: function ( value ) {
            return value.replace(':00', '');
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Then I use second function to add pips below:

```
$('#time').noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'positions',
    values: [0,25,50,75,100],
    density: 4.16
}, true);
```

And finally I linked the values to elements on a page to show selections:

```
$('#time').Link('lower').to($('#rangeFr_time'));
$('#time').Link('upper').to($('#rangeTo_time'));


<strong id="rangeFr_time">9:00</strong>
<strong id="rangeTo_time">14:00</strong>
```

So my modifications are below. I've created an array:

```
var hours = {
        0: '0',
        1: '1 am',
        2: '2 am',
        3: '3 am',
        4: '4 am',
        5: '5 am',
        6: '6 am',
        7: '7 am',
        8: '8 am',
        9: '9 am',
        10: '10 am',
        11: '11 am',
        12: 'noon',
        13: '1 pm',
        14: '2 pm',
        15: '3 pm',
        16: '4 pm',
        17: '5 pm',
        18: '6 pm',
        19: '7 pm',
        20: '8 pm',
        21: '9 pm',
        22: '10 pm',
        23: '11 pm',
        24: 'midnight'
    };
```

Then I modified the first function

```
 ...
 format: {
     to: function ( value ) {
         return hours[value];
 },
 ...
```

Now, that it displays properly in pips and on the screen I'm stuck trying to get corresponding value on a 24-hr scale into a data tag of the display elements. It should look like this:

```
<strong id="rangeFr_time" data-time-fr="9">9 am</strong>
<strong id="rangeTo_time" data-time-to="14">2 pm</strong>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6yqbbyw/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining a formatter, and using it for both the pips and a `Link` to the `#rangeFr_time` span. Don't set a format option on the slider itself, so you get the numeric output on the `data-time-fr/to` attributes.

```
function renameHour (value) {
    return hours[value];
}

var formatter = {
    to: renameHour
}

$('#time').noUiSlider({
    start: [8, 11],
    step: 1,
    connect: true,
    margin: 2,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 24
    }
}, true);

$('#time').noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'positions',
    values: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100],
    density: 4.16,
    format: formatter
}, true);

// Set attr for lower
$('#time').Link('lower').to($('#rangeFr_time'), function( value ){
   $(this).attr('data-time-fr', value);
});

// Set text for lower
$('#time').Link('lower').to($('#rangeFr_time'), function( value ){
   $(this).html(value);
}, formatter);
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/j6yqbbyw/5/) shows it in action.